# Objective C class from a Swift class

Tags: objective-c

I have a base class written in Swift that is provided to me. My job is to write additional functionality around the base class.

I am considering the swift class as super class and deriving from it. However, it isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot subclass a swift class in Objective-C.

Comment: I did not know that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Because you can’t subclass Swift classes in Objective-C, it’s best to
>   choose a class in your app that doesn’t have any subclasses.

Excerpt from Apple's guide about using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/Migration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH12-XID_67